# Summing over multiple lines with }/+

Tags: summation, notation

A Bulgarian friend of mine told me that at school, when the teachers wanted to sum over several lines, they wrote

$$
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
a-b\\c-d\\e-f\\g-h
\end{array}
\right\}
/+
\qquad\text{meaning what we would write as}\qquad
\begin{array}{l}
(a-b)+{}\\(c-d)+{}\\(e-f)+{}\\(g-h).
\end{array}
$$

I would appreciate more information about this notation if at all possible. How widespread and recognised it is, where it comes from, whether it apply to other infix operators like $×$ etc.

Comment: This might be well-suited to matheducators.se or hsm.se.

Comment: @J.G. Gosh, there are too many mathematical SE sites.

Comment: There's also mathoverflow, but this wouldn't suit that.

Comment: To me, this looks like a shorthand for doing manual computation, and not any kind of notation which one would see in a more formal setting (such as a journal article).